# Separate projects for MVC5 and Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-access-layer, asp.net-mvc-5, separation-of-concerns

I am new to **MVC** and **Web API**. I created two separate projects. One ASP.NET MVC 5 (MyUI) and other ASP.NET Web API 2 (MyApi). I would like to keep my API project separate from my UI layer.

The AccountController class in MVC project (MyUI) is essentially doing the same that the AccountController in the API project does (MyApi). I first thought about making the MyUI.AccountController a sub class of MyApi.AccountController but then I quickly realize that first inherits from Controller and second from ApiController type.

So my questions are:

1. In order to remove data access logic from MVC 5 project, should I
   just convert the AccountController to a wrapper class which will
   essentially call the corresponding methods from the
   MyApi.AccountController?
2. Is there a better approach?

**Edit:**

[image: My solution structure]

**Edit 2:**
While trying to articulate the problem I realized that I was going about it incorrectly. My confusion came from the ASP.NET Identity implementations which were embedded within the API project. That needs to be moved to the Data Access layer and both controllers need to access them the same way which is a whole different can of worms :)

Thanks!!

Comment: There is a difference between *data* models and *view* models. Your UI project should contain the models necessary for it to work, taking data from the data models provided by your WebAPI. Where you transform that data is up to you, Controller or View Model. Personally, I put that kind of transformation in public methods in my View Model

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still unclear as to how my MyUI.AccountController is going to talk to MyAPI.AccountController particularly for ASP.NET Identity routines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 seems a plausible solution but what I would suggest is to create a new class library and there put your data logic. In that way, the MVC project and the Web Api project could connect to that class library. 
The reason is that you never know if you write another UI layer, Service layer or other connectivity layer. All those layers could then connect to the same data logic layer.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the common implementation into a separate project (a class library for instance). Your business logic must be the same no matter how you access it. After all, the web service and the site are only a **view** of the same information and the same control logic. In the future you might be required to write a *fat* client in WPF or a service in WCF and you do not want to rewrite everything, do you?

Comment: Correct. I already have my data layer in a separate project. I implemented the IoC pattern so MyAPI has no knowledge of data access logic rather it just calls methods from the Data Layer project. My ultimate goal is to host my API separately so it is available externally and not tied to my UI. At some point when I get more proficient with Knockout.js I hope to convert the UI to only use Knockout and have no (or minimal) server side code. I suppose that is a lofty dream.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about layering application. basically the choice depends on requirements.If you are following data centric design  check this layering

[image]

Research about DI,ORM,Repository Pattern, SOLID Principlese